# How to calculate transform.localEulerAngles.x as negative value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object at point 0,0 and when I moved my mouse to the left side of the screen to rotate the object, `transform.localEulerAngles.x` is displaying values such as 359, 358 etc.

I was hoping that it displays -1, -2, and so on.  Is it possible to translate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Rotation > 180)
    Rotation -= 360;
```